# how to use rebar to create an erlang module with an eunit test?

Tags: erlang, rebar, eunit

My goal is quite simple; while I am learning Erlang, I would like to use rebar to create a basic module with an eunit test:

I have tried the following:

```
mkdir erlangscratch
cd erlangscratch
rebar create template=simplemod modid=erlangscratch
```

Edit the 'test/erlangscratch_tests.erl' to look like this:

```
-module(erlangscratch_tests).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

% This should fail
basic_test_() ->
    ?assert(1 =:= 2).
```

Execute the tests:

```
snowch@tp:~/erlangscratch$ rebar co eu
==> erlangscratch (compile)
==> erlangscratch (eunit)
```

The tests weren't executed, but it also seems that the code isn't compiling.

Here are the contents of my folder:

```
snowch@tp:~/erlangscratch$ tree .
.
├── src
│   └── erlangscratch.erl
└── test
    └── erlangscratch_tests.erl

2 directories, 2 files
```

**Question:** What step(s) have I missed out?

---

**UPDATE:**

As per the accepted answer, `basic_test_` function needed to be renamed and the 'src/erlangscratch.app.src' was missing so I created it with the following contents:

```
{application, erlangscratch,
 [
  {description, "An Erlang erlangscratch library"},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {modules, [
             erlangscratch
            ]},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [
                  kernel,
                  stdlib
                 ]},
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing tests with [test generators](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Writing_test_generating_functions).

In short the second one should return fun's or lists of fun's.  You can distinguish both by `_` at the end of your tests names, and `_` and the beginning of your macros.

Simple solution would be using either

```
basic_test() ->
    ?assert(1 =:= 2).
```

or

```
basic_test_() ->
    ?_assert(1 =:= 2).
```

depending on your needs, and what you understand better.

---

**EDIT** after sharing folder structure

It seems rebar is not recognizing your project as an [OTP application](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Rebar-and-OTP-conventions).  You might be just missing simple `.app.src` file.  Something like:

```
{application, myapp,
 [
  {description, ""},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [
                  kernel,
                  stdlib
                 ]},
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

And since rebar is capable of generating one for you, you either just call `rebar create-app` or extend one of existing templates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately, running `rebar co eu` still results in the same output after removing the `_` from `basic_test_()`.  I have also provided an update to my question to show the contents of my working folder.

Comment: Use the `simplelib` rebar template rather than `simplemod`, since the latter doesn't create a .app.src file, and without that rebar won't compile anything. Run `rebar create template=simplelib libid=erlangscratch` instead and, assuming you have `basic_test` rather than `basic_test_` as already suggested, it will all work as you expect.