# does rebar support tests in separate modules?

Tags: rebar

The [rebar documentation](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Getting-started) describes how to create tests inside the module you are developing (e.g. inside `src/mymod.erl`).

Does rebar support having the test code in a separate module (e.g. inside `test/mymod_test.erl`)?

Comment: Yes it does.  I forgotten that I had previously posted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100804/how-to-use-rebar-to-create-an-erlang-module-with-an-eunit-test